# Gamescom 2011 - What do you want to see covered?

Tags: discussion, blog

Good news, Gaming! My [request for sponsorship](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/gamescom-2011-sponsorship-proposal) was approved, and I'll be heading to Cologne on Wednesday in preparation for staying until Sunday to cover the event! A huge thanks to Grace Note for help in pushing this through and to Stack Exchange as a whole for sponsoring me!

Now we need your help. Gamescom is a *huge* event. I can't be everywhere at once. Unfortunately, their [event website](http://www.gamescom-cologne.com/en/gamescom/home/index.php) does not have a single, unified schedule with time blocks outlined so you can't easily see what is happening when and if it overlaps with anything else. I'm currently having to search for each company's schedule individually. So we need to narrow a few things down.

- **What games/companies/events do you really want to see covered at Gamescom?** I'm currently planning on checking out *Guild Wars 2* as I'm a big fan, Bioware for *SW:The Old Republic*, Blizzard's showing of *Diablo III* and *Starcraft II: Heart of the Swarm*, and Valve's *DotA 2* tournament. Are there other games or publishers that would *really* like to see covered?
- **Can you help us put together information for blog posts to post during the event?** For example, Valve's *DotA 2* championship is a high priority for coverage, as it's a very high profile event. However, I've personally never played *DotA*, so having someone write an article on why this is such a huge thing from the perspective of someone who has played would be awesome.

What I'll be doing is taking photos and notes and uploading them somewhere as resources for you guys to make blog posts out of. Additionally, I'm going to do a trip report-style article, hopefully each evening if I'm not completely exhausted and/or afflicted with Con Crud.

Please post and let me know what events you'd like to see covered that aren't listed, and I'll do my best to get information on it. Bonus points if you can find your publisher of choice's Gamescom 2011 schedule and/or booth number and post it with your request.

If you'd like to help out with blogging, please [check out the Gaming Blog Editor room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/386/gaming-blog-editor-room)  so you can get set up with Wordpress account, if you don't have one yet.

Comment: Good choices so far for companies.

Comment: I want to see *Magna Mundi*. But I might be *slightly* biased.

Comment: @mmyers If it's something you'd like to see, post an answer. :)

Comment: Cover _all_ the things ;)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: I would, but I'm still waiting to hear back from the project lead on potential employment - in which case I'd be spamming. :)

Comment: I don't know that there's anything else I'd _really_ like to see ... if there were three of you, there are probably little things I'd be interested in hearing about, but I expect you'll barely be able to cover all the high-interest items.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really interested in Deus Ex Human Revolution, being a huge fan of the original Deus Ex

Comment: You should get in on this then: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/gaming-promotional-grant-round-3-game-selection-thread/2573#2573

Comment: @Matthew Read I would, except I don't think I have the time to play that game right now, too much of a back log, so I'd rather someone else get the chance

Comment: @Matthew Read turns out the reviews were so good I had to move it up to the top position in my backlog to play, haha, I don't mind buying the game though, enjoying it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Another game I'm somewhat interested in is [Kingdom of Amalur: Reckoning](http://www.ea.com/reckoning) (imo dumbest sounding name ever :P), since I live in RI and the state has poured 50 million tax payer money into this possible monstrosity it better be worth it!  They said they'll have a presence at gamescon.